# Reverse sorting array inside an object based on an subarray's value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, object

My object looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["drives"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["drive"]=>
      string(11) "Drive1"
      ["features"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["statusCode"]=>
        int(1)
        ["UsedValue"]=>
        string(4) "222"
        ["TotalValue"]=>
        string(5) "22222"
        ["smart"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["drive"]=>
      string(5) "Drive2"
      ["features"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["statusCode"]=>
        int(0)
        ["UsedValue"]=>
        string(6) "2222"
        ["TotalValue"]=>
        string(7) "222222"
        ["smart"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I sort the array `drives` based on the value of `statusCode` that's inside the subarray `features`, from the highest number to the lowest?

I need to preserve this structure, I can't put the `statusCode` in the `Drive` array.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried on your own?

Comment: are there always only two elements within the `drives` array?

Comment: You can use own comparison function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uasort`(to preserve keys) function for such case:

```
// $obj is your initial stdClass object
uasort($obj->drives, function($a,$b){
    return $b['features']['statusCode'] - $a['features']['statusCode'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly :)